# How to write snippet to interact with code in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

I would like to create a snippet in R studio that can modify the code after the cursor position.

#### A working example:

change the code from `some_var: NA`  to `some_var <-`

#### What I came up so far is

```
snippet rp
    `r gsub(": NA", "<-", "$$")`
```

#### Reference

> You can also, as of RStudio v0.99.706, pass the text following the
> cursor into a snippet, using $$.

from [Rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets)

#### Problem

It didn't return what intended.

Thank you much in advance for helping with this problem!